# more pythonic way of finding element in list that maximizes a function

Tags: list, coding-style, python, maximize

OK, I have this simple function that finds the element of the list that maximizes the value of another positive function.

```
def get_max(f, s):
    # f is a function and s is an iterable

    best = None
    best_value = -1

    for element in s:
        this_value = f(element)
        if this_value > best_value:
            best = element
            best_value = this_value
    return best
```

But I find it very long for the simple work it does. In fact, it reminds me of Java (brrrr).
Can anyone show me a more pythonic and clean way of doing this?

Thanks!
Manuel

Comment: Apart from style, if you look closely enough you'll notice there are multiple bugs in this implementation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
def get_max(f, s):
  return max(s, key=f)
```